# Output id instead of the full object when serializing a list of objects

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm working with MVC 4 Web API and ran into a serialization problem I couldn't find an answer for. On to the code...

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
public class Item {
    public int ID;
    public String Name;
    public bool Active;
}

public class Source {
    public int ID;
    public int Name;
}
```

A serialized list of Items will look something like:

```
{
    ID: 1,
    Name: "That big thing",
    Active: true,
    Source: {
        ID: 1,
        Name: "The street"
    }
}
```

If there are a lot of Items in my list serializing each source into an object will get inefficient. What I want to do is only get the Sources ID when in a list. Something like:

```
{
    ID: 1,
    Name: "That big thing",
    Active: true,
    Source: 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, based on your serialized list of items, that the Item class also contains a Source property, something like:

```
public class Item {
    public int ID;
    public String Name;
    public bool Active;
    public Source Source;
}
```

If that is the case, you could add and XmlIgnore attribute to the Source property, then expose the source's id as a new SourceID property:

```
    public class Item
    {
        public int ID;
        public String Name;
        public bool Active;
        [XmlIgnore]
        public Source Source;
        [XmlElement("Source")]
        public int SourceID
        {
            get
            {
                if (Source != null)
                {
                    return Source.ID;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                // ignore incoming values
            }
        }
    }
```

It may be possible that the json library doesn't honor the Xml attributes; if that is the case, you can use its corresponding attributes (i.e. JsonIgnore, JsonProperty).

Answer (score 0):

The [JsonIgnore] suggestion posted here is a good one, but it will only work for the JSON.NET serialization.

To do this in a generic way, add a reference to **System.Runtime.Serialization** DLL and decorate your Model accordingly:

```
[DataContract]
public class Source
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ID;

    public int Name;
}
```

This would omit the Name property in any MediaTypeFormatting you use in Web API i.e.

```
<Active>true</Active>
<ID>1</ID>
<Name>test</Name>
<Source>
 <ID>1</ID>
</Source>
```

or

```
"ID":1,
"Name":"test",
"Active":true,
"Source":{"ID":1}
```